# Google Cloud Storage Object Read/Write Operation from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am accessing an object in Google Cloud Storage from my App Engine Standard Python 3 application, downloading the object to /tmp folder, editing it and then uploading this edited object back to the Google Storage:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

def edit_file(request):
        ... skipped for brevity ...
        download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name)
        with open(source_file_name, "a") as f:
            f.write(f"{x}: {y}: {z}<br>")
        upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name)
```

Is there a way to edit the object directly w/o downloading it to /tmp folder? I could not find a method for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blob object in Cloud Storage is immutable objects. So you need to download it somewhere and modify to create new object then upload it.